# why is my gravity not changing over time?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

i'm using unity 3d and I wrote a script that should theoretically make my velocity go down after time, however it's staying at a consistent -1. why isn't my code decreasing the velocity over time?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class gravity : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CharacterController controller;
    public float gravityy = -10f;
    public Transform groundCheck;
    public float groundDistance = 0.4f;
    public LayerMask groundMask;
    bool isGrounded;
    UnityEngine.Vector3 velocityy;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        velocityy.y += gravityy * Time.deltaTime;
        controller.Move(velocityy * Time.deltaTime);
        isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask);
        if (isGrounded && velocityy.y < 0) ;
        {
            velocityy.y = -1f;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting aside the many other questions I have regarding your code snippet, isn't it likely that `isGrounded` is true, thus `velocityy.y` is being set to `-1f` each update loop?

It seems like you need to use a debugger of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

### The velocity set to -1 in this loop

```
if (isGrounded && velocityy.y < 0) ;
        {
            velocityy.y = -1f;
        }
```

So you have an issue with **isGrounded**

Comment: how do I fix it?

Comment: This is you job *-*, If you delete the loop your player gravity will keep going down